# Having Arduino read a video game screen

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to connect my Arduino to my tv screen while playing a playstation/XBox game. When a certain screen comes up (like say when you die the same screen pops up) then I want Arduino to catch that and then trigger another device on and off. How might I be able to trigger something by having arduino read the screen then trigger something on and off?

Comment: This is image decoding (decoding the HDMI or composite output) there is no way an Arduino is powerfull enough to analyze the image in a viable amount of time. Plus the output of HDMI (or worst composite) is rendered so there would need to be interpolation of the colors, paterns,... 

You need something WAY more powerfull than a 16MHz uController for this kind of work.

Comment: Not a chance. The Arduino doesn't even have a fraction of the processing power needed, and only about 0.0000000001% of the memory you would need. Instead you need to use something more realistic. Maybe a Raspberry Pi with a video capture dongle and OpenCV?

Comment: There's actually not a lot of processing that needs to be done to recognize a steady computer-generated image (or a distinguishing part of one).  But you do need some ability sample (even if only one detail at a time) with an analog bandwidth comparable to the video one, and an ATmega can't do that at the resolution of a modern game system.  So at the least this would require some clever external circuitry that could be basically told "give me the value of the pixel at X, Y in the next frame" and then run that many times to check details until you've decided the game is sitting on that screen.

Comment: @EvanB, You can help improve the site who's objective is to accumulate good questions and answers by either accepting answers that work for you or refining your question (edit it) in hopes of getting a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

Most Arduino platforms contain a very low power embedded processor.  As such it is very unlikely such a device will decode an NTSC or PAL signal let alone modern digitally compressed video.

Instead consider using a light sensor attached to your monitor.  This is more in line with what, for instance, the Arduino Uno is capable of.  If you can identify a spot on the monitor that will only change to a certain brightness at the conclusion of a game, you could look for that brightness level using a light sensor attached to the monitor and connected to an Arduino.

[Here is a tutorial](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-arduino-lesson-9-sensing-light.pdf) about using a light sensor with an Arduino.  Most of the circuit is for the display of which you need not bother with.